# How can I get the user info using JWT Token in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I want to extract user info like User ID and User Name using JWT token.
I was able to do it in `django` like this:

```
    valid_data = TokenBackend(algorithm='HS256').decode(token, verify=False)
    user_id = valid_data['user_id']
    return user_id
```

but how do I do it using ruby.
Thanks :)

Comment: Ruby doesn't have built-in support for JWT, but there's the [JWT gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)

Comment: Hey @Stefan, I will check it out. I already have an user model implemented in django but I have one  more project which is in ruby so I will be using same model and need to extract user ID only.